# Undefined error in reading the property of object

Tags: javascript

Please help to solve the undefined error coming in my console while running the below code

Please see this JSbin also http://jsbin.com/ONOwujA/1/edit

```
data = [
    {key:"home",value:"hk1"},
    {key:"home",value:"hk2"},
    {key:"home",value:"hk3"},
    {key:"home",value:"hk4"},
    {key:"product",value:"pk1"},
    {key:"product",value:"pk2"},
    {key:"product",value:"pk3"},
    {key:"product",value:"pk4"},
    {key:"service",value:"sk1"},
    {key:"service",value:"sk2"},
    {key:"service",value:"sk3"},
    {key:"service",value:"sk4"}
];

myFilteredKey=[];
for(i=0;i<=data.length;i++){

    if(myFilteredKey.indexOf(data[i].key)!=-1){
        myFilteredKey.push(data[i].key);
        console.log(data[i].key);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Felix Kling: sorry to notice that difference. Now it is working thanks for the quick help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `i < data.length`. If the length is `3`, the maximum index is `2`.

Another problem with your code is that no element will be added to `myFilteredKey`. Since the array is already empty, no element will satisfy the condition `myFilteredKey.indexOf(data[i].key)!=-1`. Maybe you want to use `=== -1` instead, i.e. check whether the element is *not* in the array rather than whether it's in the array.

Comment: Thanks For the help, i corrected the two errors, now my code is running.